# cannot find an initializer for type 'String' that accepts an argument list of type '(format: String, argument: UInt32

Tags: xcode, swift, syntax-error

I created a playground in Xcode 6.3 (6D570) and input these following code:

```
import UIKit
var randum_num = arc4random_uniform(13) + 1
String(format: "card%i", arguments: randum_num)
```

And I got this error:

```
cannot find an initializer for type 'String' that accepts an argument list of type '(format: String, argument: UInt32
```

Sorry I'm complete new in Swift, thanks for any advices!

P.S. I'm following this tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lX-st90iTpk)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just have to omit "arguments:". Try like this:

```
let randum_num = arc4random_uniform(13) + 1
String(format: "card%i",  randum_num)
```

or simply

```
String(format: "card%i",  arc4random_uniform(13) + 1)
```