# format String with array of Strings

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to create a `String` with an array of `String`s, I would expect this to work:

```
let format = "%@ and %@!"
let str1 = "bla"
let str2 = "blob"

private func formatItNicely(format: String, substrings: [String]) -> String {
    return String(format: format, arguments: substrings)
}

let result = formatItNicely(format, substrings: [str1, str2])
```

but I am getting `fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes`.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724932/cannot-find-an-initializer-for-type-string-that-accepts-an-argument-list-of-ty) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905530/swift-something-wrong-with-string-initformat-method) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905530/swift-something-wrong-with-string-initformat-method) questions (and many more), but I still don't know how to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: "I would expect this to work" I don't see why you'd expect that. An array is not a variadic. The problem is that Swift has no "splat" operator. You cannot _turn_ an array _into_ a variadic.

Comment: @matt can I define my function somehow different to be able to do that? If I define the parameter substrings as `String...` I get the same result

Comment: You could just manually substitute each string for each `%@` in order, without using `String(format:)`. Otherwise you would have to get down and dirty with the C variadic stuff.

Comment: Good discussion here: https://www.drivenbycode.com/the-missing-apply-function-in-swift/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String(format:, arguments: )` expects a `[CVarArgType]` as the second
parameter:

```
let format = "%@ and %@!"
let str1 = "bla"
let str2 = "blob"

private func formatItNicely(format: String, substrings: [CVarArgType]) -> String {
    return String(format: format, arguments: substrings)
}

let result = formatItNicely(format, substrings: [str1, str2])
print(result) // bla and blob!
```

But note that this can crash (or give unexpected output) if the format specifiers do not match
the actual arguments, the formatting functions do not (cannot) check that.

Comment: I ended up doing `substrings.map { $0 as CVarArgType }` when I call `String(format:,arguments:)`. This way the substrings do not have to be `CVarArgType`

Answer (score 3):

(Nowadays) you do not have to do anything of the suggested above.

In **Swift5** you can just pass an array of `Strings` as `arguments` to `String.init(format:arguments:)`.

Therefore, the following is working fine for me without any typecasting/mapping, etc.

```swift
let formatString = "First one: %1$@, second one: %2$@"
label.text = String(format: formatString, arguments: ["hello", "blabla"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the variadic rendition:

```
private func formatItNicely(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArgType...) -> String {
    return String(format: format, arguments: arguments)
}
```

Calling it like so:

```
let format = "%@ and %@!"
let str1 = "bla"
let str2 = "blob"

let result = formatItNicely(format, str1, str2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not doing anything very interesting, you don't actually need the built-in format string logic. You can just do the substitution yourself:

```
func join(_ arr : [String], withFormatString s: String) -> String {
    var s = s
    for str in arr {
        if let r = s.range(of: "%@") {
            s.replaceSubrange(r, with: str)
        }
    }
    return s
}
let result = join([str1,str2], withFormatString:format)
```

Comment: Nitpicking: This can give wrong results if a string in  `arr` contains `%@` :)

Comment: @MartinR And in fact I was going to point out that since he isn't depending on the built-in string formatting he can provide his own extremely unlikely substitution marker. I like to use things like five upside-down exclamation marks in a row.